# Case Auto-Response rule - 'Send response to all recipients' doesn't support Email Service

Tags: case, apex-email-service, email-alert, email2case, case-auto-response

I have an Email Service, to handled incoming emails, which is replacing Email-To-Case, to handle duplicate cases (by matching the Subject of the incoming email with existing cases). This is working fine.

My issue is that the Case Auto-Response rule, is set to 'Send response to all recipients', and it is my understanding that this is only supported for Email-To-Case. 
[image]

Trying to come up with a solution, I was able to find the following article (https://customers.internetcreations.com/KnowledgeDetail?name=Include-Additional-Email-Addresses-on-Auto-Response-feature-does-not-work-with-Email-to-Case-Premium), by 'Email to case premium' which is utilizing Case Teams as part of an independent workflow rule bonded with the appropriate email alert.

Is there any way to achieve this without Case Teams? 
My Case object does have a custom 'Additional CC' (and 'Additional BCC') custom fields, which holds the email addresses of the recipients, but I am not seeing any option to add custom fields in the Email Alert:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said

> My Case object does have a custom 'Additional CC' (and 'Additional BCC') custom fields, which holds the email addresses of the recipients, but I am not seeing any option to add custom fields in the Email Alert

If those custom fields are of type `Email`, then they will appear in the Email Alert. Type Text won't work. Of course, if type `Email` the value of each field must be unitary - e.g. `foo@bar.com`, not delimited like `foo1@bar.com,foo2@bar.com`

Comment: Thanks cropredy. My 'additional CC/BCC' custom fields are Long Text, that's a bummer. I wish this was properly supported by SalesForce. Having an auto-response rule to support Email Service shouldn't be so difficult (considering the logic already exists for the Email-To-Case solution).